# angularfire2 query to read data is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angularfire2

I have data in firebase database as a list. when I use below query it does not work? why? It gives empty list

**TypeScript**

```
items: FirebaseListObservable<string[]>;

this.items = af.database.list('conversations', {
              query: {
                orderByChild: 'designer',
                equalTo: this.designerId
              }
            });
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="single-message col-md-11 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
            <div *ngFor='let item of items | async'>
          <div>
            <div>{{item.message}}</div>
            <!--<div class="date" style="margin-left:0px;">{{item.time | date}}</div><br>-->
          </div>
                  {{item.message | json}}
          </div>
          </div>
```

**Database**
http://prntscr.com/fg08hi

Comment: you should define more detailed about `it does not work`. does it return empty list? or throwing errors?

Comment: it gives empy list

Comment: I think its brings you empty list because the structure of your DB, its list inside a list. try to do the same query but like this: `af.database.list('conversations\oMX...', {` , (i mean with specific id)